# JS RegEx that matches commas within quotes

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, regex

I am trying to take a text-based log file, like below:

> type: 'click', category: 'REFRESH_DOOR', desc: 'clicked refresh from
>   door 0124', site: 'mysite', pathname: '/load_areas/all/doors', params:
>   '?sort_by=code&layout=view_by_4', time: '1515838628166', mobile:
>   'false', bp: 'xlarge', size: '[1920, 935]', area: 'all', sid:
>   '15158225889', facility: 'MMMM', IP Address: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
>   created: 'January 13, 2018 04:17'

and traverse it to build a JSON object from it. When I `log.split(",")` on the entry above to make separate objects out of the parts of the string, it takes the date and splits it up, breaking the data.

What would be a RegEx that finds commas within single quotes, which I can replace before trying to split this string into a JS array?

I basically want to change: 'January 13, 2018 04:17' to 'January 13; 2018 04:17', and worry about the conversion later.

I tried expressions like:

```
'([^']*)'
```

Which takes everything between quotes, but I haven't been able to target just commas between quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first replace the commas in question with some distinctive name and then split by this. In the end, we loop over the parts and actually build our object:

```js
var subject = "type: 'click', category: 'REFRESH_DOOR', desc: 'clicked refresh from door 0124', site: 'mysite', pathname: '/load_areas/all/doors', params: '?sort_by=code&layout=view_by_4', time: '1515838628166', mobile: 'false', bp: 'xlarge', size: '[1920, 935]', area: 'all', sid: '15158225889', facility: 'MMMM', IP Address: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', created: 'January 13, 2018 04:17'";

var regex = /'[^']+'|(,)/g;
var kv = /(\w+):\s*'([^']+)'/;

replaced = subject.replace(regex, function(m, group1) {
    if (typeof group1 == 'undefined') return m;
    else return 'SUPERMAN';
});

// create an object that holds our values
var jsonObject = {};

// create a function that splits the individual items
function splitter(item) {
 var match = kv.exec(item);
  jsonObject[match[1]] = match[2];
}

parts = replaced.split("SUPERMAN");
parts.forEach(splitter);
console.log(jsonObject);
```

---

Which yields:

```
{
  "type": "click",
  "category": "REFRESH_DOOR",
  "desc": "clicked refresh from door 0124",
  "site": "mysite",
  "pathname": "/load_areas/all/doors",
  "params": "?sort_by=code&layout=view_by_4",
  "time": "1515838628166",
  "mobile": "false",
  "bp": "xlarge",
  "size": "[1920, 935]",
  "area": "all",
  "sid": "15158225889",
  "facility": "MMMM",
  "Address": "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",
  "created": "January 13, 2018 04:17"
}
```

---

Adapted from [**The Best Regex Trick**](http://rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#javascriptcode).

Comment: @ChrisWest: If it works for you, then you might want to accept and or upvote the answer (green tick on the left).

Answer (score 0):

I changed the regex a bit to `/'.*?'/g` so it selects anything inside of quotes, and then we just do a replacement on that to find all commas and replace them with semicolons.

```js
var str = "type: 'click', category: 'REFRESH_DOOR', desc: 'clicked refresh from door 0124', site: 'mysite', pathname: '/load_areas/all/doors', params: '?sort_by=code&layout=view_by_4', time: '1515838628166', mobile: 'false', bp: 'xlarge', size: '[1920, 935]', area: 'all', sid: '15158225889', facility: 'MMMM', IP Address: 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', created: 'January 13, 2018 04:17'";

//Select all quoted strings...
var replacedCommas = str.replace(/'.*?'/g, function(match){
  //Now replace any commas found in each match with semicolons
  return match.replace(/,/g, ';');
});

console.log(replacedCommas);
```

Comment: Why do you need the `?`. Can't you just do `'.*'`?

Comment: The `?` makes it less greedy.  Without it, it would try to match as many characters as possible since `.` matches every character.  the regex `'.*'` would most likely match the first quote, and then everything between that and that last quote in the entire string since the quote also matches the `.*` pattern.  Adding the `?`makes the previous pattern (`.*`) it match as few characters as possible. This means it will match a quote, and then anything else until it encounters another quote.  Basically, it guarantees that it stops and the **next** quote and not the **last** quote.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Thanks